# Different colors for different datapoints for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have my x and y coordinates saved in variable x and y respectively. Below is the plot that I get when I make a scatter plot using x,y coordinates. The code used to make the plot is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.scatter(x[i], y[i])
```

[image: Plot Observed]

My question is that even though no color parameter was provided, plt.scatter automatically assigned different colors to the data points though the official documentation suggests that the default value is "b" as for "blue".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default seems to be `None` rather than `b` (although the detailed description of the parameters tells differently).

From the [doc](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html): `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x, y, s=None, c=None,...`

So in your case you can fix it with:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.scatter(x[i], y[i], c="b")
```

Comment: Yep, it was "b" in former times, but not anymore. I [proposed the following change](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12353):  *"Defaults to `None`. In that case the marker color is determined by the value of `color`, `facecolor` or `facecolors`. In case those are not specified or `None`, the marker color is determined by the next color of the Axes' current "shape and fill" color cycle. This cycle defaults to `rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"]`."* Feel free to give feedback on this.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Great. Thanks for the clarification and the superfast PR!